# Router obtain password hash using Linux

Tags: linux, security, hash, passwords, router

What are ways an adversary can get hold of a password hash of a router remotely, that is not the default admin password using Linux?

Does the hash of the admin password reside in certain files?

Are exploits needed to gain access to the file(s) containing the password hash?

Purpose of this is to increase my knowledge, and improve security of devices in the home.

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends on the router. If the router is based on Linux (which is often the case), access to the hashes is limited to the OS administrative user only (`root` in general). This administrative user will usually be different from the administrator account you use to connect to the router.

You therefore need to have vulnerabilities which allow you to attack services run by `root` or try to "elevate privileges", that is to use a vulnerability to have effective `root` rights going from another account.

This is to say that **you should always have an up to date device**. Unfortunately the vendors are not always quick in releasing patches when a vulnerability is discovered (often not in their devices, but in a library they use).

Comment: How about an adversary using telnet to gain root access (on a router that has telnet enabled)?

Comment: Well,  he would need to have the password or to try to get it by brute force (testing all possible combinations). If you have a long password (over about 20 characters) then you will be fine. You should not use telnet to access your router, though, especially if sdh is available. The risk is not that great but why take it at all.

Comment: How about hardcoded login credentials left in by the manufacturer, that allows an adversary backdoor access onto the router, then obtain the file including the admin password hash from there?

Comment: @Nick: it is not common to have deliberate hardcoded credentials left by the vendors. There may be *default* ones but they are usually available only on the private side of the router. There are however cases where hidden backdoors are deliberately created by the vendors. The most recent case being [Juniper](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/12/back_door_in_ju.html)